# $tan^{-1}x=180^{\circ}$ then $x=0$ TRUE or FALSE?

Tags: trigonometry

> $\tan^{-1}x=180^{\circ}$

then $x=tan180^\circ=0$

I know this is false but how can i prove its wrong?

Comment: Using the usual definition of arctangent, there _is_ no $x$ with $\arctan x=180^\circ$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki ... which makes the statement vacuously true

Comment: @StevenStadnicki sir i know that is there otherway i can do it?

Comment: But why can't i do it like this $x=tan180^{\circ}$  i am confused in this part.

Comment: i know the first part tanx domain shoulb be -90 to +90

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $$-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arctan{x}<\frac{\pi}{2},$$

we see that it's true because $p\Rightarrow q$ is true if $p$ is wrong.

Comment: But why can't i do it like this x=tan180=0 ,,i am confused in this part,,sorry its silly question i am asking...

Comment: @USER786 You just can, but by definition of $\arctan$ we have  $-90^{\circ}<\arctan{x}<90^{\circ}$ and $\arctan{x}=180^{\circ}$ is impossible.

Comment: Okay sir...Thanks....but why there is downvote in your answer

Comment: @USER786 You are welcome! I think it was because I wrote some delirium before. Later I fixed it.